# Firebase Dynamic Links - target URL is disallowed

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script

I am trying to use Google Apps Script to create Firebase Dynamic Links via API.  We're using it as a shortLink generator (kind of like the example [here](https://script.gs/use-firebase-dynamic-links-as-a-url-shortener-using-apps-script/)).

When I create the short link via the API, I get a JSON response back with the generated shortLink address.  However, when I try to visit the short link, I get the message:

```
Invalid Dynamic Link - Blocked
Target url 'https://my.destination.com/aPobMsvkVUWEGjxisRNyfA2?fn=John&mn=J&ln=Doe&ci=Nowhere&st=IL&pc=12345-6789' is disallowed.
    
If you are the developer of this app, ensure that your Dynamic Links domain is correctly configured and that the path component of this URL is valid.
```

I have added my.domain.com as a custom domain, and my.destination.com IS allowed in the domain whitelist settings within the Firebase console:

```
^https://my\.destination\.com/.*
^https://my.destination.com*
```

The strange thing is - I can create a dynamic link just fine from the Firebase console, using the same destination URL, and the redirect works!  So I suspect it's not the actual destination URL that is a problem, but rather the way in which I'm constructing or submitting the API request. Here is the relevant code in Apps Script:

```
    function myFunction() {
        
          var apiKey = "apikeyblahblahblah";

          var wholeLink = "https://my.destination.com/aPobMsvkVUWEGjxisRNyfA2?fn=John&mn=J&ln=Doe&ci=Nowhere&st=IL&pc=12345-6789";
          
          var payload = {
            "dynamicLinkInfo": {
              "domainUriPrefix": "https://my.domain.com",
              "link": wholeLink
            },
            "suffix": {
              "option": "UNGUESSABLE" 
            }
          };
        
          var options = {
            'method': 'POST',
            "contentType": "application/json",
            'payload': JSON.stringify(payload),
            muteHttpExceptions: true
          };
        
          var url = 'https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=' + apiKey;
        
          var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
          var json = response.getContentText();
          var data = JSON.parse(json);
          var obj = data["shortLink"];
          Logger.log(obj)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for me to try to get this to work?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the issue, but looking at the example codes in the firebase console, you may need the '$' sign at the end of the whitelisted domains.

> ^https://mybrand.com/.*$
> ^https://play.google.com/.*id=myapp.com$
> ^https://itunes.apple.com/.*id123$

Answer (score 0):

face this issue Dynamic Link Not Found
Short URL (https://maps.app.goo.gl/31S2tUFDPJqLVaSw294) not found

If you are the developer of this app, ensure that your Dynamic Links domain is correctly configured and that the path component of this URL is valid.

[direction](https://%20https://maps.app.goo.gl/31S2tUFDPJqLVaSw6)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).